# Connecting to localhost using paramiko in python always gives error?

Tags: python, paramiko

I am new to paramiko module for python. I want to make a remote ssh connection to a client. For now I am trying to connect to the localhost using the paramiko module but every time running the python script gives the No Valid Connection error? How can I solve this?

```
import paramiko
ssh=paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.connect('127.0.0.1')
```

This is the error I get running this script.

```
    raise NoValidConnectionsError(errors)
paramiko.ssh_exception.NoValidConnectionsError: [Errno None] Unable to connect to port 22 on 127.0.0.1
```

Comment: Your code works OK for me.  The obvious answer is that you don't have a ssh server listening on port 22 of interface 127.0.0.1 on your box.  Can you 'ssh' to 127.0.0.1 at a command prompt? - do you mean to be connecting to some other machine rather than your own workstation?

Comment: do you run SSH server on your computer ? If you don't run SSH server then you can't connect

Comment: yes even while using the command "ssh localhost" on cmd(I am using windows 10) I get the error as:" ssh: connect to host localhost port 22: Connection refused ". How to solve this?

Comment: I just installed the OpenSSH Server and client both on windows 10. The "ssh" works but not the above one.

Comment: What does it mean *"not the above one"*?

Comment: The above one means the command I showed in my first comment. But thanks anyway now its working. I had to go to the services tab in Windows 10 after installing OpenSSH Server and set the sshSever service to automatic and start the service. This solved my problem.